# XOR operation of two condtions

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor

I am new to python coding, I am writing a code checks two conditions simultaneously with xor operation
Part of code is as follows

```
if GPT[GHR]<=0 ^ LPT[pc1]<=0:
                misprediction+=1
                GPT[GHR]=0
                LPT[pc1]=0
            if GPT[GHR]>=3:
                GPT[GHR]=3
            if LPT[pc1]>=3:
                LPT[pc1]=3
```

I am perform xor operation in 1st line of code. How can I DO it

Comment: `!=` is the equivalent of xor for booleans. `false != true = true` and `true != false = true`

Comment: Sir i want something like if GPT[GHR]<=0 and LPT[pc1]<=0 which provides output by using AND truth table

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python XOR examples", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1):

`^` has a higher operator precedence than `<=`, so you would need to put the `<=` operations in parentheses:

```
if (GPT[GHR] <= 0) ^ (LPT[pc1] <= 0):
```